# Google Places API vs AJAX Search API and Local Search Control

Tags: google-maps

I've started developing a small app which main goal is to draw a map using Google Maps API (v3), and to show business in the area drawn (bars, restaurants and so on).

I found the Google Places API that was supposed to be released this month but it hasn't been. As far as I know the point of that API is to offer results from the Google's database of business, so later we could put those business in the map.

However now I've found [this sample](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/localsearch/places.html) which is using the AJAX Search API and Local Search Control for Google Maps to do the same thing.

So the question is, what is the point of the new Google Places API?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: BTW the URL for the Google Places API
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

I could just post one link before.

Comment: I am also looking into Google Places API. Have you done anything with it now? Also, I could not setup Google Maps V3 and Localsearch V2 (?) maybe due to a namespace conflict, I decided to use Maps V2 and Localsearch V2. What I came up with is something like AJAX Search API but I get more control of it because I get a JSON after querying. Mind sharing anything that might be useful to me? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places API returns a list of locations near a specific lat/lng, while the Local Search API allows for an arbitrary search of Google's database of business listings and other POIs.

Comment: Well actually the Local Search API returns locations near a specific point (lat/lng) in the map too.

I've just found a main difference which is that the Local Search API returns a maximum of 8 business near the given point. So I think that is the answer (but I am still not sure)

Comment: The Local Search API will let you do an arbitrary text search. The Places API doesn't have that feature - it just returns the closet places near a specific lat/lng. It is true you can bias local search to a particular viewport or lat/lng, but you can't do a bounded search - within a radius, for example.