# LocalSearch with Google Maps V3... but LocalSearch is deprecated?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map on my website that I want to tie to a search box to search for local business listings around a given point. With Google Maps V2, this was as simple as adding the LocalSearch component, which overlayed a box that the user could type in (eg, "pizza"), and it would return all the local business listings around that point.

However, I just found this notice that Google has deprecated the LocalSearch API and will be retiring it over the course of the next few years. How can I have the functionality described above with Google Maps V3 and... what? Google Places API? Custom Search API?

Any help would be appreciated; I haven't been able to find any examples in the wild of this being done WITHOUT LocalSearch...

Google retires LocalSearch: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-google-apis-console-and-our.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been investigating this as well and I've seen suggestions to use alternate services to get the local search data. For example, Factual, http://www.factual.com/, or Yahoo Local Search

Answer (score 1):

Places API:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Sign up for the developer preview.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this fully accomplishes what I described above... specifically, from this comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329791/google-places-api-vs-ajax-search-api-and-local-search-control: "The Local Search API will let you do an arbitrary text search. The Places API doesn't have that feature - it just returns the closet places near a specific lat/lng. It is true you can bias local search to a particular viewport or lat/lng, but you can't do a bounded search - within a radius, for example."