# Android Difference between google local search and google places api

Tags: android

I am developing app similar to restaurant locator or bank locator. I was looking through examples of `google places api`. But then I noticed `google local search` using this url http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local.

I want to know what is difference between two since both returns places based on lattitude and longitude supplied. Which one is best to use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As local search api was deprecated so I think you cannot depending on the local search as you want place then prefer the google place api instead of local search api

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

[Google Places API vs AJAX Search API and Local Search Control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3329791/760489)

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I can see there are some app stil using local search for displaying near by places. The problem I am facing with google places api is I have to make calls for getting details of each place. For example if 20 places are returned we have to make call 20 times to get detail of each place if we want to show details in list. In case of local search all required detail come with one api call.

Answer (score 1):

> Difference between google local search and google places api

Google local search is deprecated.